# To have ALL + adjective + noun

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

I am wondering whether the sentence

> That school has all smart students

is a valid alternative to

> All the students of that school are smart.

Is it idiomatic/grammatically sound? (Let's assume that there is no risk of ambiguity, namely that by reading the first sentence no one is going to think that e.g. all the smart students of the town go that school.)

Comment: Yes, native English speakers (at least in America) might say a sentence like that. But the tone is somewhat informal, and there does exist the risk of ambiguity that you mentioned. BTW, "at" is a more natural sounding preposition in the sentence, "All the students at that school are smart."

Comment: @WilliamBloom It definitely isn't a natural way of expressing the idea contained in the second sentence in British English.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence should be changed to

*That school has **/only/just/** smart students.*

to be equivalent to the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting to try to work out what

> That school has all smart students

might actually mean.  It certainly isn't a natural way of saying

> All the students of that school are smart.

One interpretation is that each student in that school is smart but has no other positive attribute. However a more likely interpretation would be that they all think they are very smart and are somewhat arrogant about it.  In particular the use of "That" in such a short sentence implies you are making some value judgement about the school rather than simply describing it.

In any case, in British English at least, it sounds like slang.

Comment: I’d say _that_ was just chosen somewhat randomly to fit a brief example; it might as well have been _this_ or _the_ (both of which would have made the sentence sound awkward, devoid of context). I wonder how you arrive at the arrogant interpretation, though—I can’t think of any way to imbue the sentence with any such meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's the use of the slang "all smart" combined with the word "That".  It sounds like they think they are "all that" or just generically are something special.  Had it started with "The" it would sound a little different you are right.  i grant you it may also sound completely different in US English.

Comment: Let’s try with an example that gives more context and thus sounds more cohesive and is less likely to sound out of place: “I grew up in a small town and was bullied a lot in school because I was ‘different’ from most of the country kids. Then we moved to London and I started at a school which had all city kids who were used to people being different, and the bullying almost completely stopped at once”. Do you find that unnatural, too? I think that is probably exactly the way I would naturally phrase it (or perhaps just “a school with all city kids”, avoiding the relative clause altogether).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's clear what you mean but it doesn't like proper English to me, no. You could perhaps say "It was all city kids at the school." as an alternative.